# Theory behind Implementation of a Challenge 24 Solver

Tags: java, algorithm

As an introduction to Java and android development I decided to write a Challenge 24 (given 4 numbers, must add, multiply, divide or subtract in order to create the product 24) solving application that implements an exhaustive technique to solve for any and all possible solutions.  currently it works like so (a,b,c,d being the 4 input numbers)

```
((a+b)+c)+d
((a+b)+c)-d
((a+b)+c)*d
((a+b)+c)/d
((a+b)-c)+d
...
...
((a/b)/c)/d
((a+b)+d)+c
((a+b)+d)-c
```

and so on...

I have found this works on a vast majority of cases, however cases such as 8,3,8,3 came up in testing where no solutions were found, however the solution 8/(3-8/3)=24 is correct.  So I guess the end question is fairly vague, but how could this be implemented to account for cases where parentheses are crucial to finding a solution?

Comment: I edited the tag because this doesn't really have anything to do with Android.

Comment: I'm curious what version of 24 you play that allows fractions in intermediate results.

Comment: @Simon: I'm curious what version of 24 you play that doesn't allow fractions in intermediate results....

Comment: Since I looked up the rules (see link in comments below), it actually doesn't say either way.  Maybe I'd just assumed that each step had to result in an integer.  That said, using a number like 8/3 would have gotten you some funny looks in my family.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider variables a,b,c,d as inputs, and +,-,*,/ as operators

you will always have three operators

```
a op b op c op d
```

Now consider the combinations of parens

```
1 group of 2
(a op b) op c op d
a op (b op c) op d
a op b op (c op d)

1 group of 3
(a op b op c) op d
a op (b op c op d)

each 3 can be comprised 
(x op y op z) as above example
(x op (y op z))
((x op y) op z)

Also, 2 groups of 2
(a op b) op (c op d)
```

Now, you must test each combination above with each set of operations:

```
 Haha silly code parser, you think these are comments in here... tsk tsk
 +++, ++-, ++*, ++/, +-+, +--, +-*, +-/,
 +*+, +*-, +**, +*/, +/+, +/-, +/*, +//,
 -++, -+-, -+*, -+/, --+, ---, --*, --/,
 -*+, -*-, -**, -*/, -/+, -/-, -/*, -//,
 *++, *+-, *+*, *+/, *-+, *--, *-*, *-/,
 **+, **-, ***, **/, */+, */-, */*, *//,
 /++, /+-, /+*, /+/, /-+, /--, /-*, /-/,
 /*+, /*-, /**, /*/, //+, //-, //*, ///
```

So, test each group of twos with those operations, each group of threes (including the simple version and the nested versions), and the one with two groups of two.

By my estimates, that's 640 tests.

This can be logically reduced, for example if `op1 == op2 == op3` then the parenthesis do not matter. There are other reductions you can make too.

Edit: You would then need to run over each permutation of a,b,c,d which would bring the total up to 15,360 (less if there are duplicates, of course.)

Comment: You would also have to run each permutation of a,b,c,d through those sets of parentheses/operators.

Comment: I wasn't aware of "Challenge 24" as a well defined puzzle.  Do you have a link for it?  Google is giving me a bunch of noise.  I've been working by these rules: http://www.24game.com/t-about-howtoplay.aspx

Comment: @Simon yes those are correct rules, and I've added it in. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much Simon and glowcoder, I just finished the code for what you guys came up with and it worked like a charm.  It was a very big help just to see a parens scheme visualized

Answer (score 3):

If you want to continue to be exhaustive, create conditions for each possible combination of parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this by enumerating the possible operator/operand combinations in a prefix or postfix notation, or building an expression tree.  That should make it easier to express them in loops and/or functions.  Then you can convert the solutions to infix for output; that's very simple if you're not concerned about superfluous parentheses.

There may be optimizations you could make to the search order that way, but the problem space is so small I wouldn't bother.